# Is this a good substr for C?

Tags: c, substring, substr

See also [C Tokenizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874161/c-tokenizer-and-it-returns-empty-too-when-fields-are-missing-yay)

---

Here is a quick substr() for C that I wrote (yes, the variable initializations needs to be moved to start of the function etc, but you get the idea)

I have seen many "smart" implementations of substr() that are simple one liner calls strncpy()!

They are all wrong (strncpy does not guarantee null termination and thus the call might NOT produce a correct substring!)

Here is something maybe better?

Bring out the bugs!

```
char* substr(const char* text, int nStartingPos, int nRun)
{
    char* emptyString = strdup(""); /* C'mon! This cannot fail */

    if(text == NULL) return emptyString;

    int textLen = strlen(text);

    --nStartingPos;

    if((nStartingPos < 0) || (nRun <= 0) || (textLen == 0) || (textLen < nStartingPos)) return emptyString;

    char* returnString = (char *)calloc((1 + nRun), sizeof(char));

    if(returnString == NULL) return emptyString;

    strncat(returnString, (nStartingPos + text), nRun);

    /* We do not need emptyString anymore from this point onwards */

    free(emptyString);
    emptyString = NULL;

    return returnString;
}


int main()
{
    const char *text = "-2--4--6-7-8-9-10-11-";

    char *p = substr(text, -1, 2);
    printf("[*]'%s' (\")\n",  ((p == NULL) ? "<NULL>" : p));
    free(p);

    p = substr(text, 1, 2);
    printf("[*]'%s' (-2)\n", ((p == NULL) ? "<NULL>" : p));
    free(p);

    p = substr(text, 3, 2);
    printf("[*]'%s' (--)\n", ((p == NULL) ? "<NULL>" : p));
    free(p);

    p = substr(text, 16, 2);
    printf("[*]'%s' (10)\n", ((p == NULL) ? "<NULL>" : p));
    free(p);

    p = substr(text, 16, 20);
    printf("[*]'%s' (10-11-)\n", ((p == NULL) ? "<NULL>" : p));
    free(p);

    p = substr(text, 100, 2);
    printf("[*]'%s' (\")\n", ((p == NULL) ? "<NULL>" : p));
    free(p);

    p = substr(text, 1, 0);
    printf("[*]'%s' (\")\n", ((p == NULL) ? "<NULL>" : p));
    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

> Output :

```
[*]'' (")
[*]'-2' (-2)
[*]'--' (--)
[*]'10' (10)
[*]'10-11-' (10-11-)
[*]'' (")
[*]'' (")
```

Comment: While we're at it, printf("%s\n", NULL) will print "(null)\n" rather than crashing in some massive error, so you shouldn't have to check whether or not p is NULL inside your printf()s.

Comment: Actually, I can't find anything in any standards regarding the behavior of printf() when given NULL as a string, but that's what it does on my system (OS X Leopard).

Comment: Yes Chris, I too have got (null) on all OS I have worked on, but then strcmp() with a NULL dumped core on Solaris (or was it HP-UX?) but it does not do that on others.. so why bother with a small ternary?

Comment: From C11: "... `%s` ... the argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type". So NULL is _not_ acceptable as per the standard. You bother with that small ternary if you want your code to be portable :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: In other words I coded it right 2 years ago and not listening to Chris was a good idea :-D?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say return `NULL` if the input isn't valid rather than a `malloc()`ed empty string. That way you can test whether or not the function failed or not with `if(p)` rather than `if(*p == 0)`.

Also, I think your function leaks memory because `emptyString` is only `free()`d in one conditional. You should make sure you `free()` it unconditionally, i.e. right before the `return`.

As to your comment on `strncpy()` not NUL-terminating the string (which is true), if you use `calloc()` to allocate the string rather than `malloc()`, this won't be a problem if you allocate one byte more than you copy, since `calloc()` automatically sets all values (including, in this case, the end) to 0.

I would give you more notes but I hate reading camelCase code. Not that there's anything wrong with it.

EDIT: With regards to your updates:

Be aware that the C standard defines `sizeof(char)` to be 1 regardless of your system. If you're using a computer that uses 9 bits in a byte (god forbid), `sizeof(char)` is still going to be 1. Not that there's anything wrong with saying `sizeof(char)` - it clearly shows your intention and provides symmetry with calls to `calloc()` or `malloc()` for other types. But `sizeof(int)` is actually useful (`int`s can be different sizes on 16- and 32- and these newfangled 64-bit computers). The more you know.

I'd also like to reiterate that consistency with most other C code is to return `NULL` on an error rather than `""`. I know many functions (like `strcmp()`) will probably do bad things if you pass them NULL - this is to be expected. But the C standard library (and many other C APIs) take the approach of "It's the caller's responsibility to check for `NULL`, not the function's responsibility to baby him/her if (s)he doesn't." If you want to do it the other way, that's cool, but it's going against one of the stronger trends in C interface design.

Also, I would use `strncpy()` (or `memcpy()`) rather than `strncat()`. Using `strncat()` (and `strcat()`) obscures your intent - it makes someone looking at your code think you want to add to the end of the string (which you do, because after `calloc()`, the end is the beginning), when what you want to do is set the string. `strncat()` makes it look like you're adding to a string, while `strcpy()` (or another copy routine) would make it look more like what your intent is. The following three lines all do the same thing in this context - pick whichever one you think looks nicest:

```
strncat(returnString, text + nStartingPos, nRun);

strncpy(returnString, text + nStartingPos, nRun);

memcpy(returnString, text + nStartingPos, nRun);
```

Plus, `strncpy()` and `memcpy()` will probably be a (wee little) bit faster/more efficient than `strncat()`.

`text + nStartingPos` is the same as `nStartingPos + text` - I would put the `char *` first, as I think that's clearer, but whatever order you want to put them in is up to you. Also, the parenthesis around them are unnecessary (but nice), since `+` has higher precedence than `,`.

EDIT 2: The three lines of code don't do the same thing, but in this context they will all produce the same result. Thanks for catching me on that.

Comment: Your assertion about the 3 lines of code being same is wrong.

strncat is guranteed to suffix a 0 after copying int the source string.
strncpy is not guranteed to suffix a 0 after copying, but it will stop the copying process as soon as it comes across the first \0..
.. and we all know what memcpy is :-)

Comment: They are not the same, but in this context they will all produce the same result. My point is that strncat does a lot of extra (and in this case, unnecessary) work than strncpy or memcpy.

Answer (score 7):

Your function seems very complicated for what should be a simple operation. Some problems are (not all of these are bugs):

- `strdup()`, and other memory allocation functions, *can* fail, you should allow for all possible issues.
- only allocate resources (memory in this case) if and when you need it.
- you should be able to distinguish between errors and valid stings. At the moment, you don't know whether `malloc()` failure of `substr ("xxx",1,1)` or a working `substr ("xxx",1,0)` produces an empty string.
- you don't need to `calloc()` memory that you're going to overwrite anyway.
- all invalid parameters should either cause an error or be coerced to a valid parameter (and your API should document which).
- you don't need to set the local emptyString to NULL after freeing it - it will be lost on function return.
- you don't need to usr `strncat()` - you *should* know the sizes and the memory you have available before doing any copying so you can use the (most likely) faster `memcpy()`.
- you're use of base-1 rather than base-0 for string offsets goes against the grain of C.

The following segment is what I'd do (I rather like the Python idiom of negative values to count from the end of the string but I've kept length rather than end position).

```
char *substr (const char *inpStr, int startPos, int strLen) {
    /* Cannot do anything with NULL. */

    if (inpStr == NULL) return NULL;

    /* All negative positions to go from end, and cannot
       start before start of string, force to start. */

    if (startPos < 0)
        startPos = strlen (inpStr) + startPos;
    if (startPos < 0)
        startPos = 0;

    /* Force negative lengths to zero and cannot
       start after end of string, force to end. */

    if (strLen < 0)
        strLen = 0;
    if (startPos >strlen (inpStr))
        startPos = strlen (inpStr);

    /* Adjust length if source string too short. */

    if (strLen > strlen (&inpStr[startPos]))
        strLen = strlen (&inpStr[startPos]);

    /* Get long enough string from heap, return NULL if no go. */

    if ((buff = malloc (strLen + 1)) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    /* Transfer string section and return it. */

    memcpy (buff, &(inpStr[startPos]), strLen);
    buff[strLen] = '\0';

    return buff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char* emptyString = strdup(""); /* C'mon! This cannot fail? */
```

You need to check for null. Remember that it still must allocate 1 byte for the null character.

Answer (score 0):

strdup could fail (though it is very unlikely and not worth checking for, IMHO). It does have another problem however - it is not a Standard C function. It would be better to use malloc.

Comment: For what it's worth, strdup() is easy enough to write that you might as well use it, and use autoconf or something similar to check if you need to roll your own version.

Comment: strdup is now removed .. people were being too pedantic ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the memmove function to return a substring from start to length.
Improving/adding another solution from paxdiablo's solution:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    char *splitstr(char *idata, int start, int slen) {
            char ret[150];
            if(slen == NULL) {
                    slen=strlen(idata)-start;
            }
            memmove (ret,idata+start,slen);
            return ret;
    }

    /*
    Usage:
            char ostr[]="Hello World!";
            char *ores=splitstr(ostr, 0, 5);
            Outputs:
                    Hello
    */
```

Hope it helps. Tested on Windows 7 Home Premium with TCC C Compilier.